When I use the code in jupyter to run the Gemma model on Huggingface, the following error appears:
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /google/gemma-7b (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f46f24f09b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
maybe proxy has  problem？
I tried changing proxy settings with code like below,but no effect...
import os

os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:10808'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:10808'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:10809'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'https://127.0.0.1:10809'

